# Compiling LaTeX document makes Google Drive crash

Tags: macos, latex, google-drive

I've the issue that when I compile a LaTeX document that is located inside my Google Drive this will after a few turns make the OSX Google Drive application crash.

As this is an important document I want to keep it all the time inside the Google Drive location to ensure cloud backup but this ofcourse is not guaranteed if this makes my Google Drive crash all the time.

I don't seem te be able to identify what is causing this and I was hoping that maybe some people here have any idea what might cause this? We're talking about a 8 pages document with 3 images, so nothing crazy big or complex.

/edit. to complete the picture this is the error google drive gives:

> An unknown issue occurred and Google Drive needs to quite. Error:
>   PRIMARY KEY must be unique

With the suggesting if this happens often you should try to disconnect your account.

Comment: What happens if you pause Google Drive while you're compiling?

Comment: It doesn't crash. For some reason my gut feeling says it becomes when compiling several files change at the same time. And then especially when you compile a few times after each other (fixing image issues for example) Google Drive crashes.

Comment: I would suggest, then, that a Google Drive folder is not a good place for a lot of quick file changes in rapid succession. (I wonder if Dropbox or SkyDrive has the same sort of issue.) I would suggest either pausing the Google Drive service while you're compiling, or compile in a temp directory and only put the final product in the Google Drive folder.

Comment: Dropbox never had this issue before but I made my move to Google to keep all my files/emails/pictures in the same cloud as that saves money :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have no such problems with dropbox =P

now ... I'd guess that this is due to latex creating an deleting temporary files, such as .aux

To solve that, you might use some hacks to prevent the creation of said files inside the google drive.

My first idea would be to use `pdflatex -output-directory /a/dir/ouside/the/google/drive`. The files would be generated outside your google drive, but the sources would still be there (and, therefore, safe)

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search shows that this is a very common problem. The suggested fix is to look for conflicting files and remove them manually.

You can read the whole conversation [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/drive/8DNEH3U6vbE).